# How to bulk create/import users in Azure AD so that all of them can have single sign on to my SF sandbox?

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-active-directory

I am working on Using Single Sign on for my Salesforce sandbox. I am using Azure AD as the authentication provider. I was able to add a few users in Azure AD and actually got the Single sign on working for my SF sandbox (for those users). The problem is my sandbox has 500 users and I would like to add them all to my Azure AD. Here is the document I followed to get the single sign on working for my test users. So my next step/question is how do I bulk uloa all my user information in Azure AD so that all of them can have single sign on to my SF sandbox?
Thank you

Comment: By importing user information if you mean creating new Azure AD users with this information then you can make use of PowerShell and `Import-csv` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) to import all userinformation.. then use `New-AzureADUser` command to create these users.. A very detailed script here.. https://charbelnemnom.com/2018/03/how-to-create-bulk-users-in-azure-active-directory-with-powershell-azuread-powershell-aad/

Comment: Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have all user information available in a CSV file, you can make use of PowerShell and [Import-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) to import all userinformation.

Then use `New-AzureADUser` command to create these users. Skeleton like this..

```
foreach($user in import-csv "E:\userinfo.csv") 
{ 
   Write-Host "Processing item with.. UserName="$user.DisplayName

   # Make use of variables like $user.DisplayName and so on in your commands here..
   # New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $user.DisplayName ... and so on..
}
```

A very detailed script with similar strategy is availble here: [Creating Bulk users in Azure AD with PowerShell](https://charbelnemnom.com/2018/03/how-to-create-bulk-users-in-azure-active-directory-with-powershell-azuread-powershell-aad/)